# React Hotkeys keymap gives type error in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm using the example in the docs

```
const keyMap = {
    CONTRACT: "alt+down",
    COMMAND_DOWN: { sequence: "command", action: "keydown" }
};
```

I'm getting this error.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<GlobalHotKeysProps>): GlobalHotKeys', gave the following error.
    Type '{ CONTRACT: string; COMMAND_DOWN: { sequence: string; action: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'KeyMap'.
      Property 'COMMAND_DOWN' is incompatible with index signature.
        Type '{ sequence: string; action: string; }' is not assignable to type 'KeySequence'.
          Property 'sequences' is missing in type '{ sequence: string; action: string; }' but required in type 'ExtendedKeyMapOptions'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: GlobalHotKeysProps, context?: any): GlobalHotKeys', gave the following error.
    Type '{ CONTRACT: string; COMMAND_DOWN: { sequence: string; action: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'KeyMap'.  TS2769
```

React Hotkeys : https://github.com/greena13/react-hotkeys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the datatype of keyMap as KeyMap.

```
import { KeyMap } from 'react-hotkeys';

const keyMap: KeyMap = {
    CONTRACT: "alt+down",
    COMMAND_DOWN: { sequence: "command", action: "keydown" }
};
```